# Send information from Server to android app

Tags: android, web-applications, web, send

I would like to know how can I send some information (like a number, a string...) from my web application to an android app which installed at my phone.

E.g., when some event happens in my web application it sends a signal to my mobile.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send push notifications when you want notify clients about something.
As example use
[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate that way :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question:

[how to send data from website server to android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292929/how-to-send-data-from-website-server-to-android-app)

It talks about using [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)